# Prove that $\min(S)$ does not exist for $S=(0,1)$

Tags: real-numbers

> Prove that $\min(S)$ does not exist for $S=(0,1)$.

I'm taking the proof by contradiction route i.e. assuming m = min(S) then trying to find some sort of contradiction.

I've tried take m=2m-1 and take m = (m-1)/2 but neither seem to work?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $m \in S$ is your candidate minimum, consider $m/2$.

Comment: Consider m1 = m/2. then 0<m1<1 there m1 is in S. But clearly m1<m....contradiction!

Comment: Right!${}{}{}{}$